# is the integral of any polynomial of the form $a+bt+ct^2......+dt^n$ from zero to t always not zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, linear-transformations

For instance,

I am looking at a question in linear algebra,

Define $T : P_{3}\to P_{4}$ such that

$T(p)=\int_{0}^{t}p(x)dx$

find the Nul(T)

This ends up being = {0}.   Since this is true I was wondering how no polynomial is from zero to t where t is the dimension of the polynomial is zero

Comment: @lulu I don't even know that Nul(T) = 0 was the answer. I was given this fact and it made me immediately of all polynomials in general .

Comment: Sorry, my comment was irrelevant.  Without my glasses, I incorrectly read the limits of integration as $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$T(p)=0\implies $$
$$\frac{dT(p)}{dt}=0\implies$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^tp(x)dx=p(t)=0$$

Comment: @PeterForeman The derivative wrt $ t$ of $T(p)$ is $ p(t)$. This is FTC.

Comment: yes, I see that  this is the answer for the proving that the set of all polynomials that are integrated from zero to t, that are equal to zero is the {0}. Therefore proving only the trivial solution exists. It's just strange that this is the case

Comment: @PeterForeman Do not forget the coefficients.

Comment: it's strange that the integral of any polynomial from zero to t, where t is the degree of the polynomial is never zero. If you imagine it graphically in $R_{2}$ it basically says that all functions that are polynomials  don't have an equal distribution of area above and below the x=0 line between y=0 and y=t. That is why it is strange. I had no idea that what I was learning just proved something so large, in my mind at least. I mean the application of integration of polynomials plays such a large part of most of the math and physics I have done so far. So, to hear this is just strange.

Comment: @ConradG It is quite possible for these areas to be equal for some fixed values of $t$ (roots of the integrated polynomial) but it's not going to be zero for all values of $t$ which is the assumption we are making here. If the area above and below is **always** equal then clearly the function has to be the zero polynomial as we have concluded.

Comment: @PeterForeman I see what you are saying now. Got it

Comment: @PeterForeman sorry to beat a dead horse but could you provide an example of a polynomial function that integrates to zero between o and t where t is the degree of the polynomial

Comment: @ConradG I'm not completely sure what your question is but an example relevant to our previous discussion is$$\int_0^1 (2x-1)\mathrm{d}x=0$$